# Is it possible to override autoincrementing keys when QGIS inserts into SQLite?

Tags: qgis, sqlite

I have a table, without any geometry, loaded in QGIS 1.8.0 (from OSGeo4W) via the `Add Vector Layer` option.  The table resides in a SQLite/SpatiaLite database, and has a field named "id" that was created with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` option.  From SpatiaLite GUI or SQLite Manager in Firefox, I can add a new row using any unique 64-bit integer value for "id".  However, an attempt to add the same row from QGIS results in "id" being autoincremented.  My question is: Is there a way to override or fix this behavior?

According to http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html it is valid to assign a value (within constraints) to an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a geospatial problem but an SQL problem.

**Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement because PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL.** ( see [SQLite: Frequently Asked Questions: 1) How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1), [SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#primkeyconst) or [StackOverflow: No autoincrement for Integer Primary key in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490100/no-autoincrement-for-integer-primary-key-in-sqlite3))

You need to use SQL to understand why:

- If I create a table in the SQLite shell with

[image]

SQLite uses id instead of the internal primary key named "rowid" because the value of a PRIMARY KEY can not be null

[image]

- If I want to impose a specific value to the PRIMARY KEY

[image]

but if the key exist :  [image]

An if I continue without imposing a PRIMARY KEY, the autoincrement continue:

[image]

> However, an attempt to add the same row from QGIS results in "id" being autoincremented

**It is the normal behaviour, otherwise the value of the primary key is null**

Comment: I think you missed the point. This is not an SQL issue because I get the expected result when using SQL.  I  entered a valid value  for "id" in QGIS, and did not receive the expected result.

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem, if you wan to use the table as a complete SQLite table, you must use the DB Manager plugin (Database/DBManager menu) or other one

Comment: Good idea to use DB Manager -- I forgot about that since I use other tools for db operations.  Your answer is very thorough and would probably be helpful to someone searching for info, so I will accept it as correct within a few days absent any more specific information about QGIS.  Thanks.